# How do I get the width of the iOS keyboard with UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is there a way to get the width of the system keyboard on iOS with UIKit? When the device is in landscape mode, the keyboard doesn't extend all the way to the end of the screen. Specifically, I want to find the width of the keyboard from the q key to the p key. I am writing a toolbar above the keyboard that will have custom keys, and I need them to be positioned just like the default keyboard. Is there any way to do this?

[image: iOS Keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to determine the displayed width of the keyboard. All you need to do is setup the input accessory view correctly and the buttons will appear with the desired margins.

Start by subclassing `UIInputView`. This should always be used for custom input accessory views. You can either add buttons and other content directly to the view or you can add a `UIToolbar` and add items to the toolbar as needed.

Following is two classes demonstrating the two techniques.

No toolbar, just a couple of buttons:

```swift
class MyAccessoryView: UIInputView {
    var button1 = UIButton()
    var button2 = UIButton()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero, inputViewStyle: .keyboard)

        // Setup the buttons however you need.
        // Add any other subviews like labels or images
        var cfg = UIButton.Configuration.borderedTinted()
        cfg.title = "Toolbar1"
        button1 = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
        }))
        button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        cfg = UIButton.Configuration.borderedTinted()
        cfg.title = "Toolbar2"
        button2 = UIButton(configuration: cfg, primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { action in
        }))
        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(button1)
        addSubview(button2)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // This sets up the first button to line up with the left edge of the keyboard
        // and the second button to line up with the right edge of the keyboard.
        // Note the use of layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
            button1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            button2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
            button2.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // Use this to provide a recommended height. The width will fill the width of the keyboard
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 320, height: 50)
    }
}
```

Here's a version that uses a toolbar:

```swift
class MyAccessoryToolbar: UIInputView {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero, inputViewStyle: .keyboard)

        // Setup whatever items you need
        // The flexible space ensures the Cancel button is on the left edge
        // and the Done button is on the right edge
        toolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .cancel),
            UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .flexibleSpace),
            UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .done),
        ]

        // We want to make the toolbar clear so the background of the input view shows through
        let tba = UIToolbarAppearance()
        tba.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        toolbar.standardAppearance = tba

        toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(toolbar)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Simply fill self with the toolbar. The toolbar automatically ensures
        // its buttons have the appropriate margins
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            toolbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            toolbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            toolbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            toolbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // Match the toolbar's size
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return toolbar.intrinsicContentSize
    }
}
```

Here's the keyboard on an iOS 17 iPhone 15 Pro simulator in landscape:

[image]

Note that the sets of constraints are very different between the two approaches. With a `UIToolbar`, the toolbar ensures the proper margins of the buttons.